# How to pass password value string contains ! in nagios command for monitoring purpose

Tags: string, nagios

In nagios cfg if I want to pass multi parameters to command, the value is seperated by !

My problem is that the password I'm trying to pass to nagios cfg file contains !, which causing problem for nagios to think it's a separator.
Is there any other way to change seperator or literally change the meaning of ! in password string?
e.g.

```
define service{
 use generic-service
 host_name 10.62.85.10
 service_description ESXi Hardware Check
 check_command check_esxi_hardware!root!Password123!!auto
}
```

nagios thinks the `$ARG1$` is root `$ARG2$` is Password123 and `$ARG3$` is null

actually the value I want to pass is 
 `$ARG1$` is root `$ARG2$` is Password123! and `$ARG3$` is auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use Nagios user macros for store sensitive information like password. Just look to your Nagios `private/resource.cfg` file for more information.

Nagios uses `!` to separate input arguments in the configuration.
Everything is great until you need to use a `!` or `$` within one of your variables. At this point you need to escape the special character.

You should use a backslash "`\`" to do this for the `!` and `$` characters in your Nagios configuration files, like: `\!` or `\$`.

Comment: thanks a lot - it works at my side using \ to escape the !

Comment: I happy to see, that everything is working for you. If you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as "accepted solution".